# Created and Modified Time of ITEM in SharePoint List required in Milliseconds

Tags: sharepoint-online, date-time, powerapp, powerapps-forms, powerapps-canvas

Is there a way of retrieving the created and modified time in Seconds and Milliseconds?

Currently in the SharePoint list it seems it only gives u the dates like this 2021-02-08 17:23. What I need is 2021-02-08 17:23:30:599. This is required as users can potentially add entries for the same customer etc.

The SharePoint List is connected to a Power App .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Milliseconds cannot be retrieved, but we can retrieve created and modified time in seconds. Create two calculated columns and use the following formulas respectively:

```
=TEXT(Created,"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM")

=TEXT(Modified,"MM/DD/YYYY hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

**Test result:**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use below formula on label control to show the Created field in specific format:

```
Text(ThisItem.Created, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

OR

```
Text(ThisItem.Created, "[$-en-US]mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
```

**Output**:

[image]

**Documentation**: [Text function in Power Apps](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/functions/function-text)

---

You can also add fraction of seconds like:

```
Text(ThisItem.Created, "[$-en-US]mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss.fff AM/PM")
```

But for me, it always returns 000. So maybe SharePoint does not provide this information in Power Apps.

[image]